# 13.04 The Software center stopped working after update: an unhandled error occured

Tags: 13.04, apt, software-center

I've done a clean installation of ubuntu 13.04 2 weeks ago and I can't say the usual user experience that I knew for ubuntu is not there.

I just did an update and restarted my machine as asked then, I realized I can't install anything any more. the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1185, in _simulate
trans.high_trust_packages) = self.__simulate(trans)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1304, in __simulate
unauthenticated = self._get_unauthenticated()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 451, in _get_unauthenticated
for origin in pkg.candidate.origins:
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 479, in origins
origins.append(Origin(self.package, packagefile))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 145, in __init__
self.archive = packagefile.archive
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Can anyone shed some lights on what's happening, and what are my options?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

produces the following:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/gh.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudp apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

then try again.

**answer for edit :**

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/list/gh.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply this is what I am seeing:  sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/gh.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: still no luck. it didn't work at all

Comment: Give me log of your terminal

Comment: Hi sorry for the late update, I removed all under `/var/lib/apt/lists` leave partial folder out and did `apt-get update` again and it downloaded the files again and it started working again. I have left office monday , i will check if it's still working. thank for everything